# What is the proper way to end a faulted API request from the server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http, .net-core

We have an API endpoint where users can upload files. Sometimes these files are very large, up to 1GB. When a user sends the request to upload a file the clients have to wait until the request is finished before they can receive a response. Normally this does not cause any issues but if the user uploads a very large file that has errors they may have to wait many minutes before they receive an error message (file type not accepted, invalid file signature, etc).

To avoid this bad UX when we detect an error I have tried aborting the connection to prevent the upload of the bad file continuing any further than it needs to:

```
var uploadResult = await _assetUploadCommand.AddMultipartAsset(requestData);
if (uploadResult.Faulted)
{
    Response.StatusCode = uploadResult.Error.HttpStatusCode;
    Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", uploadResult.Error.Message.Length.ToString());
    await Response.WriteAsync(uploadResult.Properties.Error.Message);
    await Response.Body.FlushAsync();

    HttpContext.Abort();

    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This works ok when I upload an invalid file locally - it returns the proper status code, with the error message in the body. In our test environment however all the client receives is `Error: read ECONNRESET` with no information on what went wrong or why the file was bad, which is an equally bad UX as having to wait for the response.

I realize this is not a good way of dealing with long running bad requests but I have been unable to find any other solutions to this problem other than aborting the request. Is there a better way of doing this? Please note that I have no control over the clients.

Comment: Whats the type of the server? ECONNRESET sounds very server specific. And what a server returns to your client is Server business and isn't typically fixable on the client. If the server does not send more you don't have more to show.

Comment: I don't think you should be aborting the context or returning an empty result. Try to return something like `BadRequest([...])` or an appropriate `IActionResult` response and see what it says.

Comment: @Ralf It is an IIS server. It just means that there was a TCP RST message.

Comment: @Daevin Doing that means that the user has to wait a long time to receive the response if the request file has errors. If I didn't care about the bad UX I would just do as you suggest.

Comment: I might have missed the point. What you want to break early for big erroneous files happens in _assetUploadCommand.AddMultipartAsset so need to be dealt with in that method(i thought that would be a call to a different server that returns ECONNRESET)  or it happens before this code when uploading data to this code?

Comment: @TridentTrue what is the process that continues after the error is detected? Have you tried using a `CancellationToken` on any awaitable tasks instead of just `await`ing them? That might be the solution instead of aborting the context (I'm not super familiar with ECONNRESET, but that might be a consequence of the `Abort()` call).

Comment: @Daevin The server has already responded within a second of the request being received but the client continues to upload the bad file as it does not read the response until the request is completed. I thought CancellationToken was for serverside only? Is there a way to return a CancellationToken to the client to prompt the remaining upload to stop?